# FOR /R %%i return some strange things

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

```
pushd %~dp0
set actdir=%cd%
mkdir "%cd%\numbers"
SET count=1
for /R %%i in ("C:\Users\me\Desktop\bt") do (call :subroutine %%i %~xi)
GOTO :eof
```

Trying to recursively get all files from a folder (and subs too), to copy/rename them to a different path.

%%i is returning something very very strange. exactly, this:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\RunningBatchFolder\"C:\Users\me\Desktop\bt"
```

so something like two combined paths.
How comes? how to fix that please?

Plus another problem, %~xi gives an error : `The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~xi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

```
for /R "C:\Users\me\Desktop\bt" %%i in (*) do (call :subroutine %%i %~xi)
```

Here's more [info](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html):

```
    Unlike some other variants of the FOR command you must include a wildcard 
   (either * or ?) in the 'set' to get consistent results returned. In many    cases
    you can work around this by adding a single character wildcard e.g. if you 
    are looping through multiple folders to find the exact filename myfile.txt 
    you could instead specify myfile.t?t
```

Comment: this working perfectly `for /R "C:\Users\me\Desktop\bt" %%i in (*) do (call :subroutine "%%i")`  then for the extension, using `%~x1` in the subroutine. thank you